# How to verify input value is within range or not in elastic search Using DSL QUERY

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-6

I have two entity like User & Activity. Activity contains filed ageGroup like ["10:20","25:30"] & user entity contained age field . consider user age is 26 so he/she is eligible for that activity.
I want to fetch all those activities which satisfied above conditions

```
GET _search
{
"query": {

    "bool": {
        "filter": {
          "range": {
            "ageGroup": {
              "gte": 50,
              "lte": 55
            }
          },
          "term": {"****": "M"}
        },  
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {"******": {"value": "15"}}

        }
      ] ,"should": [
               {
                   "match": {"******": "7"}
               },
               {
                   "match": {"******": "1"}
               }
            ]
    }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use integer_range  data type to verify  value within range or not
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/range.html

Answer (score 0):

Include(Entity/Object) contain List

```
public class Include {
@Field(type= FieldType.Nested)
private List<AgeGroup> age;
}
```

Data : 
   {....., include.age:{ "id": 4, "minAge": 4, "maxAge": 9 }, { "id": 3, "minAge": 1, "maxAge": 4 }, .....}

**DSL Query :**

```
GET /_search
    {
        "query": {

         "bool": {
           "should": [
                {"range": {"include.age.minAge": {"lte": 9}}},
                {"range": {"include.age.maxAge": {"gte": 9}}
                }
              ],"minimum_should_match": 2
         } 

        }
    }
```